# asp.net button javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Not Working!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function click() {

                AjaxFileUpload1_UploadOrCancelButton.click();
            }

        </script>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:click(); return false;" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Not working! Best question I seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="click();" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this form:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="click();" Text="Button" />
```

And in the code behind of the page:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;")
```